# Inconsistent type for section in UITableViews

Tags: iphone, uitableview, overflow

In some places, sections are referred to as NSIntegers

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

But in NSIndexPath, they are clearly defined as NSUIntegers.

```
section
An index number identifying a section in a table view. (read-only)

@property(readonly) NSUInteger section
```

Aside from the obvious overflow implications (would have to be a really big table), this creates a lot of annoyance for me since I turn on the Sign Comparison compiler warning option.

Anyone aware of a valid reason for this, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I'm assuming this is just bad design and dealing with it.  Oh well.